# unable to perform Iteration with R

Tags: r

I've been practicing with the Titanic dataset and have made steady progress. However, I have got stuck when I try to to replace the missing 'Age' variables with the median age depending upon certain conditions. Here is the dataset:

```
| Pclass | Name      |   Sex  | Age |
|:------:|:---------:|:------:|:---:|
|    2   |  officer  |  male  |  NA |
|    3   |  mr       |  male  |  27 |
|    3   |  miss     | female |  NA |
```

Now, I want to replace the NAs with the median ages that i calculated and leave the age already present as it is. For this I used the following code for iteration:

```
age_fill <- function(x){ 

    for (i in length(x$Age)) {

      if (!is.na(x$Age[i])) {
          return(x$Age[i])

      }

      else if(is.na(x$Age[i])){


        if (x$Sex[i] == "female" && x$Pclass[i] == "3" && x$Name[i] == "miss"){
          x$Age[i] = 18
        }

        if (x$Sex[i] == "male" && x$Pclass[i] == "2" && x$Name[i] == "mr"){
          x$Age[i] = 29
        }

        if (x$Sex[i] == "male" && x$Pclass[i] == "3" && x$Name[i] == "officer"){
          x$Age[i] = 25
        }

     }

  }
  return(x)
}
```

The problem here is nothing changes when i run the code as a **function** or in a **loop**. However, if I run it separately by putting in the digits of the row, it returns the results just fine.

Can someone pls tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide us with a reprex, also don't do what you are doing on a prediction exercise, I don't know why you would need && when & should work fine

Comment: What is `x` inside your function? You don't assign `x` anywhere. Afaik your changes to `comb` only exist inside your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Your Question

Regarding your function there are several issues:

```r
age_fill <- function(x){ 

    for (i in length(x$Age)) {

      if (!is.na(x$Age[i])) {
          return(x$Age[i])

      }
# some more code
}
```

1. Your `for`-loop just loops over one element: `length(x$Age)` returns one value. I guess you mistook it for `1:length(x$Age)`.
2. If your function encounters a non-`NA` value, `return(x$Age[i])` will break/stop your function and return one value. I don't think that is what you want. In the case of a non-`NA` value you want your function not to change anything. Therefore you should remove this whole part:

```r
      if (!is.na(x$Age[i])) {
          return(x$Age[i])

      }

      else
```

Your condition

```r
if(is.na(x$Age[i])){
# enter code here
}
```

is sufficent.

#### Alternative approach

Here is a solution using `dplyr`. It's not a direct answer to your question but I want to show you another approach to your problem. Given a dataset

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Pclass Name    Sex      Age
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
1      2 officer male      NA
2      3 mr      male      27
3      3 miss    female    NA
4      3 mr      male      NA
5      2 mr      male      NA
6      3 officer male      NA
```

that I created with package `readr`

```r
df <- read_table2("Pclass  Name        Sex   Age
    2     officer    male    NA 
    3     mr         male    27 
    3     miss       female   NA 
    3     mr         male     NA
    2     mr         male     NA
    3     officer    male     NA")
```

Now we use `mutate` combined with `case_when`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Age = case_when(!is.na(Age) ~ Age,
                         Sex == "male"   & Pclass == "3" & Name == "officer" ~ 25,
                         Sex == "male"   & Pclass == "2" & Name == "mr"      ~ 29,
                         Sex == "female" & Pclass == "3" & Name == "miss"    ~ 18
                        ))
```

which yields

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Pclass Name    Sex      Age
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
1      2 officer male      NA
2      3 mr      male      27
3      3 miss    female    18
4      3 mr      male      NA
5      2 mr      male      29
6      3 officer male      25
```

Using this approach you don't need a function nor any kind of loop and your conditions are clearly arranged. As a rule of thumb: Try avoiding loops. Usally there are more sophisticated ways of performing a task without loops. R uses "hidden loops" inside functions optimized for performance. However there are tasks well suited for loops. So the decision depends on the actual task.

Comment: Thank you Martin....it solved the problem and the alternate approach is much better so i'm integrating that. Your explanation about the whole problem is really helpful, will keep them in mind. Thanks again !

Comment: A little "guideline": You want to change data inside a data.frame and you have a set of conditions: there are better ways then `for`-loops. You have to run several functions and produce several different outputs: a `for`-loop might be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the function has a parameter x and returns x, but the for cycle is aplied to a (I guess) data.frame "comb". In order to perform a call to the function
`output <- age_fill(comb)` you should replace `comb$myVariable` by `x$myVariable` so that all the operation within the for cycle can be applied.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my part in writing the code here. Even with the 'comb' as 'x' it gives the same result that is no change appears while running `output <- age_fill(comb)` but the table comb is copied as it is again.